# Adicionar tabla a Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, identity, code-first

Uso VS 2017, quiero crear una tabla Solicitudes y relacionarla con la tabla AspNetUsers, de uno a muchos... un AspNetUser que tenga muchas Solicitudes... quiero la opción api fluent, pero estoy algo atascado con el código. Se de code first que AspNetUsers debería tener:

```
public virtual Solicitud Solicitud { get; set; }
```

Y que la otra tabla debe tener:

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Pero con Identity, no se dónde poner las cosas

```
public class Solicitud
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaYHora { get; set; }
        public String Tipo { get; set; }
        public bool AprobadoPorRH { get; set; }
        public bool AprobadoPorJefe { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Y en IdentityModels

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public virtual Solicitud Solicitud { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Solicitud> Solicitudes { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>()
           .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(s ⇒ s.Id)
           .WithMany(t ⇒ t.Solicitudes)
           .HasForeignKey(u ⇒ u.Id);

        }
    }
```

Que cambios debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> quiero crear una tabla Solicitudes y relacionarla con la tabla AspNetUsers, de uno a muchos... un AspNetUser que tenga muchas Solicitudes.

Estas haciendo lo contrario a eso ya que si un `usuario` tiene varias `solicitudes` debes tener una colección o lista de `solicitudes` por cada `usuario`. Y cada `solicitud` debe pertenecer a un solo `usuario`.

Así que de esta manera seria tu modelo de `solicitud` tomando en cuenta lo dicho al principio:

```
public class Solicitud
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaYHora { get; set; }
    public String Tipo { get; set; }
    public bool AprobadoPorRH { get; set; }
    public bool AprobadoPorJefe { get; set; }

    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Y para agregar una la referencia de las solicitudes en el modelo del `usuario`(en este caso el de identity *ApplicationUser*) agregar la propiedad de navegación.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual List<Solicitud> Solicitudes { get; set; }
}
```

Y en tu api fluent, es decir, en `OnModelCreating()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>() .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Usuario)
            .WithMany(x =>x.Solicitudes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UsuarioId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Recalco el enfoque de este modelo es que un `usuario` puede tener varias `solicitudes` y que cada `solicitud` pertenece a un `usuario`.

Comment: Hola Denifier, me sale el tipo de propiedad usuarioId de la entidad solicitud no coincide con la propiedad Id de la entidad ApplicationUser en la restricción referencial solicitud_usuario @denifier

Comment: Lo solucioné así:  [Key]
        public int IdSolicitud { get; set; }    le cambié el tipo de dato a la clave foránea ya que me di cuenta que la primary key de AspNetUsers es nvarchar   public String Id { get; set; }      también cambié esto     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Usuario)
                .WithMany(x => x.Solicitudes)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

Comment: Gracias, olvidé ese punto

Comment: Lo solucione, para futuros usuarios con el mismo caso.

Comment: Gracias @denifer